# Looking for best ways to deal with categorical data for ML

Tags: python, statistics, data-science

I have been using one hot encoding but this just increases the dimension size (curse of dimensionality). I have also done this and converted to Principal Components, however this is good, but doesn't tell me much about the chosen principals. It also doesn't always work when I need ordinal approach to variables like education levels.

My question is:

**What common workplace techniques do you use to deal with datasets that contain some categorical data or nearly all categorical data?**

Remembering that the data can be bother nominal or ordinal.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Not quite on-topic for SO. This question should go to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com). But normally you would encode the data. You can do OH encoding or, assign numeric values, especially when dealing with ordinal data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Hashing — Is like OneHot but fewer dimensions, some info loss due to collisions. It works for Nominal and ordinal data:

Read more about it here: [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/smarter-ways-to-encode-categorical-data-for-machine-learning-part-1-of-3-6dca2f71b159) and [here](https://booking.ai/dont-be-tricked-by-the-hashing-trick-192a6aae3087)